# regular expression to define a language

Tags: regex

Can some one help with defining a regex for language L while strings in L don't contain 101 as a substring? (if only 0s and 1s are allowed)

I already have `(1|0)*[^(101)]` but it does reject all the strings in the language.

Comment: What engine/language?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I think he's talking about [the L programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_(programming_language)).

Comment: Its about writing a program in Java to define a language L={w|w doesn't contain 101 as a substring}   P.S I am a She :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*?101)[01]+$
```

in front of your regex.